# Firebase Hosting and Github Action error "auth/invalid-api-key"

Tags: firebase, github, environment-variables, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I'm using React for my project along with Firebase. Using Github Actions my code is successfully deployed to firebase.
But when I visit the **hosted URL** It gives me an error in the console saying

```
"Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly."
```

However when I deploy from the local system directly using `firebase deploy` It works fine.

I have taken the required care of my environment variables. But nothing seems to work.

**It seems there is some problem while GitHub actions deploy the changes to firebase.
 Though all the build pass it gives me an error as stated above. Please Help.**
[image]

Comment: are you using the ci token? the one you get from firebase login:ci

Comment: No. I created my app from the firebase console.

Comment: Are you using a .env file in your local system to store your firebase configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This happen because GitHub actions don't have access to your `.env` on your local machine, you need to configure that on "GitHub Secrets" and put on your `yml` file.