# env file with Github Actions

Tags: reactjs, github, environment-variables, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I'm using React and firebase. I have a `.env` file with my secrets stored at the root of my project.

How can I access the `.env` file in the GitHub workflow yml file.

How should I proceed as best practice?

Answer (score 1):

## DO NOT DO THIS

Checking that into your GitHub project is a **super bad idea**. Added emphasis there because once keys are in your git repository you're basically in huge trouble and it is a massive hassle to undo. You never, **ever** want to commit keys to your repository. Just don't.<sup>1</sup>

Instead what you need to do is make use of GitHub Secrets either at your organization/personal level, where they can apply to your projects by default, or per-project. These can be used within GitHub actions as things like:

```
${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME }}
```

Where those will be substituted based on the secret value.

GitHub Secrets are like a secure<sup>2</sup> version of your `.env` file variables.

---

<sup>1</sup> You may think having a private repository protects you here, but it may not. Other team members may download this and inadvertently push it somewhere else. You may open-source it later without realizing. Mistakes happen because you assumed you'd never expose these keys.

<sup>2</sup> Of course these are only as secure as GitHub is, and they could be exposed by someone with a sufficiently high level of access even if GitHub makes it difficult to see them casually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added my `.env file` secrets into GitHub secrets and named it `REACT_APP_API_KEY`. Here is my `.yml` file [.yml](https://pastebin.com/3hC3kRAZ). But I ran into the same issue I describe in the earlier question I asked [auth/invalid-api-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231107/firebase-hosting-and-github-action-error-auth-invalid-api-key)

Comment: You should split out the individual environment variables as different secrets, but I guess you can stuff the whole thing in there, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should never commit a .env files with secret key.

For this, you can use [GitHub encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I ran into the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231107/firebase-hosting-and-github-action-error-auth-invalid-api-key). You can find my [.yml](https://pastebin.com/3hC3kRAZ) if required.

Comment: Also, I do not commit my .env file to Github. Actually, I'm using Github actions to automatically build and deploy to firebase when a change is detected. But it seems Github actions is not provided my secrets that's why when I visit the hosted URL It gives me an error saying `Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.`